# Google Go AppEngine imports and conflicts when serving / testing

Tags: google-app-engine, go

So I have spent the better part of two days trying to figure this one out and no matter what I do I can't get things straightened out. Here is what is going on:

- Using Go and Appengine. I am running into issues when trying to
  get proper unit tests working.
- I have tried lots of structures but here is a sample of where I am now: https://github.com/markhayden/SampleIssue
- I am running into dependency issues in either `goapp serve` or `goapp test -v ./src/lib1` depending on how I have my import paths set.

If I use `"src/lib1"` for my import path and then `goapp serve`. My app boots and runs fine, but when I run tests I get the following failure:

```
src/lib1/lib1.go:5:2: cannot find package "src/lib2" in any of:
    /Users/USERNAME/go_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/src/lib2 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/markhayden/Projects/go/src/src/lib2 (from $GOPATH)
```

Likewise, if I use `"dummy/src/lib1"` as my path, my tests are happy and run fine but upon `goapp serve` ing the app I now get:

```
2014/11/06 20:33:34 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file lib1.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH
```

Have fiddled with all sorts of different options and can't figure out how to handle dependencies and still have solid testing. Maybe its a appengine / golang bug? Or am I missing something?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

Updated everything based on first comment feedback. I can run tests (as I was able to do before) but I still can not serve the app. Here is what I get when running `goapp serve`

```
INFO     2014-11-07 17:24:48,727 devappserver2.py:745] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2014-11-07 17:24:48,748 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:60732
INFO     2014-11-07 17:24:48,751 dispatcher.py:185] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-11-07 17:24:48,754 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2014-11-07 17:24:49,041 go_runtime.py:171] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /Users/markhayden/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /Users/markhayden/Projects/go/src/github.com/markhayden/SampleIssue -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /Users/markhayden/go_appengine/goroot -nobuild_files ^^$ -unsafe -gopath /Users/markhayden/Projects/go -print_extras_hash lib1/lib1.go lib2/lib2_test.go main_test.go main.go lib1/lib1_test.go lib2/lib2.go)

2014/11/07 09:24:49 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file lib2.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH
```

$GOPATH = `/Users/markhayden/Projects/go`
$GOROOT = not set (according to docs it doesnt need to be if you dont use a custom directory)

App Structure:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/markhayden/SampleIssue/
 - app.yaml
 - /lib1
    - lib1_test.go
    - lib1.go
 - /lib2
    - lib2_test.go
    - lib2.go
 - main_test.go
 - main.go
```

In main.go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/markhayden/SampleIssue/lib1"
    "net/http"
)
```

In lib1/lib1.go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/markhayden/SampleIssue/lib2"
)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Appengine "conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH" issue:

Appengine is importing things underneath the root directory (i.e. where the app.yaml is).  This will cause two imports, one by appengine when it scans the directories, and a second by your source when it is explicitly imported.

You have two choices:

**Don't use the full import path (for sub-folder packages) with appengine.**

- Remove the source repository part of import.  So instead of
  "github.com/blah/blah" it would be "blah/blah".

  *Note:* This kinda sucks as it makes your build and software appengine specific. You could make this a little better -maybe- by using [build constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).  e.g. `+build !appengine` or
  `+build !appengine` to include/remove certain files from the build depending on if you are targeting appengine.

**Move your modules/dependencies (sub-folders) to a separate and independent project to make it work with the full path import convention:**

1. Get rid of all directories / dependencies in the main project (where
   your app.yaml is), so that appengine can't scan and find them.
2. Move them to another independent project (I did SampleIssueDeps)
   with no app.yaml that is **not** a sub-directory (e.g.
   /MarkHayden/SampleIssueDeps).
3. Then pull those dependencies via
   full path import.  e.g. github.com/MarkHayden/SampleIssueDeps/lib1.

**Summary:** For sub-folder packages in an appengine project don't include the "source repository" part of the import path OR only use appengine to init() and move all of your other code to separate projects and use like external dependencies.

Comment: First, thanks so much for taking the time to look things over. Second, I have read through "how to write go code" a few times and organzed several projects outside of appengine with no issue. This one is organized a little wonky because I have been trying to solve the issue and moving things around. Regardless, I started fresh trying your above method exactly and still having issues. Added what I'm seeing to the original post due to length.

Comment: To make it work with your directory structure (which I'd still fix to be more conventional) you can make your import match whatever is after your GOPATH. e.g. import "SampleIssue/app/src/lib1".  If I pull down your app locally into $GOPATH/github.com/markhayden/ and fix your import statements to be everything after my $GOPATH e.g. "github.com/markhayden/SampleIssue/app/src/lib1" then everything works.  Notice how I had to include the /app/src/ directories.  That said, I'd kill the app and src directories and move everything in src to a SampleIssue folder, then your import will be far simpler.

Comment: Yah I changed the structure per your recommendations (added an update above). So now my gopath is `/Users/markhayden/Projects/go` and my directory structure is shown here: http://f.cl.ly/items/1r2N46432K1z0j0w0T0N/dirstruct.jpg

Comment: Also updated the github repo with the current files for "SampleProject"

Comment: Its basically feels like if I use paths relative to my $GOPATH, the tests are fine. but when I serve its loading everything twice, thuse generating the error. On the flipside, if I use paths relative to my app, it serves fine because imports are only loaded once but tests fail because it cant find the necessary dependencies. Kinda feeling like an appengine test bug? But you are saying you can run `goapp serve` from the main app as well as `goapp test -v` from say the lib1 directory?

Comment: FWIW. Just tested on a linux machine that I am positive is set up per googles standards (same as your reco matt) and it has the same exact issue.

Comment: Ok, with your new organization, I reproduced the "conflicts with the same file imported from GOPATH" issue.  It appears that appengine is scanning for imports manually underneath the root (where the app.yaml file is) and those are conflicted with your explicitly imported paths.  Adding to answer above...

Comment: btw - I'd change your question title to "Google Golang AppEngine imports and conflicts" or something.  To more accurately reflect where this went... :)

Comment: Good call, also that seems to have worked in the sample app. Going to move my main project over to the same setup and see if all is good (fingers crossed). Thank you so so so much for taking the time on this. Will definitely give you credit once the main app is running. Standby!

Comment: Have it working now. Ended up putting everything in one master folder, then the structure recommended so it could all live in one repo but everything seems to be working. Will have to rework a few things but seriously can no thank you enough.

Comment: I am trying this solution but can't get it to work.. I'm remembering this to be a problem last time I started a google app engine project. If someone have time to look at my problem, can you see my post about it. Thanks! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677358/google-app-engine-cant-build

Answer (score 17):

I came up with another option that isn't discussed here and in my opinion is much easier to deal with (and keep your app less appengine specific). Lets say you have the repo at `github.com/blah/blah` and right now the root folder of the repo defines your app engine server.

First, move the `app.yaml` and other app engine specific files (NOT `.go` files) into `github.com/blah/blah/appengine/app.yaml`.

Next, wherever you run your init function for app engine, rename it to something like `func Run() { ... }`, and then in `github.com/blah/blah/whatever.go` write something like this:

```
package appengine

import "github.com/blah/blah"

func init() {
    blah.Run()
}
```

From my experience this has resolved the issue and made things much easier. I'll update this if I run into any major issues that make this a bad solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Definitely a much cleaner solution (and avoids namespace incompatibility).

Comment: Works perfect. I tried the accepted answer, but could not get atom to agree with the solution even if it compiled. This solution however compiles, and agrees with atom(go-plus).

Comment: I find solution documented [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/zL4uLQfVS7c) rather more fitting for such cases. Pay careful attention to `nobuild_files:...` app.yaml configuration.

Comment: @iswak in my defense the thread you link to was created 10 months after my answer, much like this comment is super delayed ;)

Answer (score 4):

I had a lot of trouble following various answers and understanding how to solve the problem.

But after a lot of research, I believe I understand both cause and solution:

Google app-builder tooling does some path-munging and is causing this.
They are aware of the bug but no ETA to fix it.

Problem summary:
any .go files **inside or below** the directory holding main.go / app.yaml will be double imported…

In summary, just make sure that ALL of our files/packages are **siblings** and not decedents of the directory holding those two files...

Comment: I'm doing services inside the same code repo and didn't notice the slight structure difference between my folders - this was indeed my issue. Thanks Dewey. As a side note - this only seems to matter if the project is self-referencing i.e. you link between packages in the same project.