# Go Package Conflict

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am new to Go and AppEngine. I am trying to figure out how to create packages but I keep running into conflicts. My directory structure is below:

```
GOPATH
 third-party-libs 
 app 
  app.yaml
  controllers
     default.go -- package controllers
   models
     models.go -- package models
   templates
     templates.go  -- package templates
```

I am importing the templates package as follows `import ("app/templates")` inside `default.go`

When I do `goapp serve` I get this error:

```
Failed parsing input: app file templates.go conflicts with 
same file imported from GOPATH
```

I have tried a bunch of things and nothing has worked so far. These are things I have tried:

1. Changed the `templates` directory to `apptemplates` and the corresponding file to `apptemplates.go`, changed package name to `apptemplates`. I imported it as `app/apptemplates`
2. I tried different combinations by changing the file name but not the package name, vice versa, etc. Either it does not find the file or has a conflict.
3. I am importing `html/template` in my `templates.go` file. So I commented out the entire file just keeping the package declaration but did not make the conflict go away

I thought may be another file is named templates.go but when I do this (at the `GOPATH` level) `find . -name "*.go" | grep "templates.go"` I only see the one file I have created.

I am confused as to how packages are created. I have changed the name to something generic so it does not look like a naming issue. Can someone please tell me how I can debug this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Go AppEngine imports and conflicts when serving / testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794225/google-go-appengine-imports-and-conflicts-when-serving-testing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the package to a non-conflicting name as in #1.  Import the package using the path "apptemplates".

Packages inside of the application directory (the directory containing app.yaml) are imported with a path relative to the application directory. See [Organizing Go Apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/runtime#Go_Organizing_Go_apps) for the complete details.

Comment: Here's an updated link for [Organizing Go Apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/runtime#Go_Organizing_Go_apps)