# How do I store the private key of my server in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, jwt, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using `"github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"` to create JSON web tokens.
When I hosted my server locally, I could use my private key as usual. But in GAE it won't work because I don't have access to the file system.

How would you guys do it? Store the key in datastore or any other ideas?

Thanks

Edit:

My `app.yaml` looks like this (below `api_version` and stuff):

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On AppEngine you don't have access to the file system of the host operating system, but you can access files of your web application (you have read-only permission, you can't change them and you can't create new files in the app's folder).

So the question is: do you want to change this private key from your application without redeploying your app? Or it is perfectly fine if it is deployed "statically" with your app's code?

If you don't need to change it (or only when you redeploy your app), easiest is to store it as a "static" file as part of your webapp. You may refer to files of your app using relative paths, where the current or working directory is your app's root. E.g. if your app contains a `key` folder in its root (where `app.yaml` resides), and there is a `my_key.txt` file inside the `key` folder, you can refer to it with the path: `key/my_key.txt`.

Actually it is quite common to "ship" static files with your app's code: just think of HTML templates which are read and processed by the Go code (e.g. package [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/)) to produce HTML result; the content of the HTML template files are not served directly to clients.

If you need to change it from time to time without having to redeploy your app, then store it in the Datastore which your app can read and modify.

**Note:**

One important note: not every file is readable by code, this depends on the app configuration. Quoting from [Configuring with app.yaml / Static file handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers):

> Static files are files to be served directly to the user for a given URL, such as images, CSS stylesheets, or JavaScript source files. Static file handlers describe which files in the application directory are static files, and which URLs serve them.
>
> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately from application files. Static files are not available in the application's file system. **If you have data files that need to be read by the application code, the data files must be application files, and must not be matched by a static file pattern.**
>
> Static file handlers can be defined in two ways: as a directory structure of static files that maps to a URL path, or as a pattern that maps URLs to specific files.

Read the link how to properly configure application and static files / directories.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer!

Comment: Maybe not something you want to dig into, but I cant get it to work when I deploy my code. The path for key works when serving local. I get the keys by doing ioutil.readfile("keys/demo.rsa") and from root there is a folder called keys, which both demo.rsa and demo.rsa.pub is in. My file which includes them lies in another folder at the same level as keys. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand Please see edit. Files that need to be read by the code must be _application files_ and must not match any _static file pattern_.

Comment: I have read the page at the link and I think I know what I want to do. But I cant get my code to deploy now. Errors in app.yaml.  I only had - url: /.*
  script: _go_app first. Now i have - url: /keys
  static_dir: keys
  application_readable: true. Does this look good?

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand Your first version where you only have one `_go_app` entry looks perfect. Your second example is bad: it exposes your key to be publicly available! Revert that change!

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, felt bad. But the code doesnt compile with the second part. Should I have app.yaml with only "handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app". Dont I have to say anywhere in the file how to find the keys? That was what I got from reading the link

Comment: I feel that I might not understand what you mean. Shouldnt I say in app.yaml what files to serve to my app? Or should I do it inside the golang code?

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand By default all files will be application files. But if you define `static_dir`s and `static_files` in your `app.yaml`, those will be excluded from static files (unless you also specify `application_readable` to the static resource). In your case it should work with `"keys/demo.rsa"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99978/discussion-between-simon-nilsson-guldstrand-and-icza).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to leave app.yaml as it were. Put app.yaml at root lvl in project. Then change all imports from starting at GOPATH to start at project root instead. The problem that made me choose to put app.yaml and main go file in a different folder under project root was because of double imports. Read this for a better understanding: [Google Go AppEngine imports and conflicts when serving / testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794225/google-go-appengine-imports-and-conflicts-when-serving-testing)

The solution made my project find the files I wanted.