# Google App Engine cant build

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Im having problem with building my project, i.e, "goapp serve".

I get this message:

```
Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /Users/simon/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /Users/simon/Programming/golang_projects/src/googleglass_backend -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /Users/simon/go_appengine/goroot -gopath /Users/simon/Programming/golang_projects -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_rebuild -unsafe -print_extras_hash handlers/mainpage.go types/user.go types/data.go handlers/utils.go server.go)

2017/01/16 14:04:30 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file data.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
 golang_projects
    bin
       ...
    pkg
       ...
    src
       googleglass_backend
           app.yaml
           handlers
               utils.go
               mainpage.go
           index.yaml
           server.go
           types
               data.go
               user.go
```

My GOPATH looks like this:

```
/Users/simon/Programming/golang_projects
```

I dont know what data.go could be conflicting with?

My server.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "googleglass_backend/handlers"
    "googleglass_backend/types"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "encoding/gob"

    "net/http"

    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func init() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    gob.Register(types.User{})
    //For all includes in html files
    router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web/static/"))))

    router.HandleFunc("/", handlers.IndexTemplate)
    handler := cors.Default().Handler(router)
    http.Handle("/", handler)

}
```

Contents of data.go:

```
package types

import (
    "time"
)

type Data struct {
    xaxis        int
    yaxis        int
    beacon_1     int
    beacon_2     int
    beacon_3     int
    RegisterTime time.Time
}
```

Comment: what is the `package` in your `data.go` file?

Comment: Editing with data.go in question

Comment: what happens when you do a direct build: `go build $gopath/src/googleglass_backend/server.go`?

Comment: Try changing the struct and file name to something else - Data and data.go are very non-descriptive

Comment: Since I'm using google app engine, I dont have a main function. It says: 
go build /Users/simon/Programming/golang_projects/src/googleglass_backend/server.go 
# command-line-arguments
runtime.main: call to external function main.main
runtime.main: main.main: not defined
runtime.main: undefined: main.main

Comment: @Sridhar, when I change it to beacondata, it says the same thing but with the new name. Am I importing them twice?

Comment: Yes it would appear so. What's your GOROOT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Go AppEngine imports and conflicts when serving / testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794225/google-go-appengine-imports-and-conflicts-when-serving-testing)

Comment: @Sridhar my GOROOT is blank.. But I dont think I am using GOROOT when using the google app engine? Am i?

Comment: @RickyA ill check that! Thanks

Comment: @RickyA Im following the instructions on that page you linked but I cant seem to get it working. I am positive that is the error, ie importing twice. I am trying to change my imports to not include the domain, only importing types, not googleglass_beacon/types. But that wont work..

Comment: Try moving types to /Users/simon/Programming/golang_projects/src/, i.e. up one directory and import in googleglass_beacon app as types

Comment: That's one of the solutions in the link that @RickyA posted. Make types a package outside the appengine directory.

Comment: Hmm. That seems to work, but I wont be able to version stuff with git as easily now..?

Comment: I cant really understand what to do with the last answer on this question? Can someone explain what files should be where? Since I dont think having types and handlers beside the project.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794225/google-go-appengine-imports-and-conflicts-when-serving-testing

Comment: If you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34390759/1093710) that's suggesting having only 2 files in the app folder - app.go (with init) and app.yaml. You could also just dump everything in the single folder and not have a separate package for types and handlers.