# How to make golang gin work with google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, dev-appserver, google-app-engine-go, dev-appserver-2

My GOPATH is `$HOME/go`, I put my project's source code in `$HOME/go/src/myproj`

and there are two files:

**app.yaml:**

```
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

and **hello.go**

```
package hello

import (
        "net/http"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func ping(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
        })
}

func init() {
        r := gin.Default()

        api := r.Group("/api")
        {
          api.GET("/ping", ping)
        }

        http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

Then I run `dev_appserver.py .`

It works,

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/ping
{"message":"pong"}
```

Then I decide to split hello.go this way:

new **hello.go**

```
package hello

import (
        "net/http"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "./api"
        // "myproj/api" // does not work too
)

func init() {
        r := gin.Default()

        api.addRoute()

        http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

and a `api` folder, and `api/api.go` file

```
package api

import (
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func ping(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
        })
}

func addRoute() {
        api := r.Group("/api")
        {
          api.GET("/ping", ping)
        }
}
```

Then I run `dev_appserver.py .` again but got this error:

ERROR    2018-09-28 05:17:47,653 instance_factory.py:229] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /Users/gaco/.google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.9/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /Users/gaco/go/src/myproj -api_version go1 -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /Users/gaco/.google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.9 -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_rebuild -unsafe -print_extras_hash hello.go api/api.go)

2018/09/28 14:17:47 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file api.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH

WARNING  2018-09-28 05:17:47,654 instance.py:297] Could not get PID of instance
ERROR    2018-09-28 05:17:47,654 instance.py:300] '_GoBuildFailureRuntimeProxy' object has no attribute '_process'

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Go AppEngine imports and conflicts when serving / testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794225/google-go-appengine-imports-and-conflicts-when-serving-testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized this is a problem I had once in my own App Engine project. The problem is that because your `api` folder is nested beneath your `myproject` folder. The SDK doesn't handle the imports well and things end up recursively imported, hence the `2018/09/28 14:17:47 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: app file api.go conflicts with same file imported from GOPATH` error.

Effectively, you have to make sure you are never importing something down a directory, which is really annoying.

To solve this, given the info here, you would need to break this out into a more flat directory structure. Something like this:

```
myproject/main // or however you want to name it
myproject/api
```

With nothing in the bare `myproject` folder. Then there is no possibility for it to be included recursively.

For reference, my own project has a website, api, db, and 3rd party api structs, so my structure is as you'd expect given the solution mentioned. e.g.

```
project/website
project/api
project/db
project/external
```

Note that both my website and api are separate services, so they both have their own `app.yaml` in their respective directories. You would just have the one. Also in my example, both projects import `db` and `external`.